# Aspect Maven Plugin 'overriding' already enhanced Datanucleus classes

Tags: google-app-engine, maven, maven-3, aspectj, datanucleus

I'm using the aspectj-maven-plugin together with datanucleus enhancement done by the appengine-maven-plugin.
In case I define the aspectj-maven-plugin before the appengine-maven-plugin everythings seems ok, but when I define the appengine-maven-plugin before the aspectj-maven-plugin then the aspectj-maven-plugin seems to override class enhancements done by the appengine-maven-plugin.

Of course I can just define the aspectj-maven-plugin before the appengine-maven-plugin but I wonder if there are better sophisticated ways to solve this problem?

This is my configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <aspectLibraries>
            <aspectLibrary>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            </aspectLibrary>
        </aspectLibraries>
        <outxml>true</outxml>
        <source>${java.version}</source>
        <target>${java.version}</target>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
                <goal>test-compile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
    <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${com.google.appengine.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>enhance</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use *overweaving* in order to get this working.  Typically, AspectJ assumes that it is the only bytecode transformer operating on a classfile.  So, before it weaves, it will always go back to the original (not transformed class file).  When you have something like datanucleus in play, this assumption no longer holds. Overweaving is an option that weaves over an already woven class.

More details here: http://andrewclement.blogspot.ca/2010/05/aspectj-overweaving.html

To enable, use the `-Xset:overWeaving=true` option to enable it.  However, looking at the comments below the blog post, I can see that maven doesn't like the `-Xset:` options.  So, the suggestion is to use a .lst file and add the -X option to that instead.

If this doesn't work, I'd suggest emailing the aspectj-users mailing list.